# Javascript gauge - webdriverjs execution hook inside a class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, getgauge

New to javascript and gauge .

Here is my what I am trying to do using webdriverJs, gauge

I have 2 classes

- base - for initiating driver
- home page - which has elements and methods for home page
- then my test file which will have my step implementations

Similar to java, here is my base class

```
webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
let driver;
class BasePage {

"beforeScenario hook here to initialize driver"
//{
    //this.driver=   new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();  
//}
getDriver (){
    return this.driver;
}
navigate (){

    await  this.driver.get('https://google.com');
}
}

module.exports = BasePage;
```

- And my HomePage which extends BasePage

```
let basePage= require('./basePage')

class HomePage extends basePage {


//other home page functions
{driver.findElement(element).click}

}

module.exports = HomePage;
```

- here is my test

```
let homePage = require('./HomePage')
step("open <site>", async function(){

    let h1 = new homePage();
   await  h1.navigate();


});
```

The idea is to initiate the driver in the baseclass and have it available to all the classes which extend base class . At the end, I should be able to run the tests parallel . **But the challenge is that I am not able to successfully write the execution hooks inside the base class.**
Can somebody help me understand if I am trying to do something which i conceptually wrong . Are there better way to achieve what I am trying?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: With gauge, it is not recommended to use the page object pattern, for the same reasons you're experiencing this issue. please look at https://blog.getgauge.io/are-page-objects-anti-pattern-21b6e337880f

Comment: also discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/getgauge/5Im9CqArGX0/w6wQncB7FAAJ